# Apply formatting to a cell if its values don't match that of another cell (or group of cells)

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Excel snapshot]

I have an Excel document that is formatted similarly to the one pictured above. It is, however, very large. The ID and Flag fields are proprietary and will *never* change between SSN's.

I basically need to use ID to compare the 'OLD' records to the 'Source' records. If the column value of the 'OLD' record doesn't match any of the column values for the 'Source' record(s), fill that cell yellow.

I'm familiar with Access VBA but I've never written it in Excel and I'm not sure where to start, or if this is even possible. I've tried to include examples in my image.

You'll notice, for example, that Amy Winer's OLD SSN does not match up to either of her source SSNs, so that cell is yellow.

Where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the column `D` from `D2` downward, and enter this custom conditional formatting formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,D:D,D2,F:F,"source")=0
```

and set the format/fill to yellow.

---

To apply the same rule to all column `B` through `E`, select the range `B2:E7` and use the CF formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,B:B,B2,$F:$F, "source")=0
```

Notice that we **fix** the columns `A` and `F` using `$`, and make the others movable

Comment: Can you explain this formula to me? I'll have to change slightly how it's applied. What do A2 and D2 represent? Those values will not apply to all records in the sheet.

Comment: @Steven `A2` and `D2` will apply to the first record. Since they are **relative**, they will be shifted with each record (A3 and D3 will aply to row 3 and so on). The formula checks if there is at least one `source` record with the same `ID` and `SSN`.

Comment: I believe I can actually leave A2 alone and just change D2 to E2, F2 and so on as I progress to the other columns. It seems to be working, so thank you!

Comment: @Steven, that's right. But you can even make it simpler, sorry I didn't notice you want it for all columns. You can make only one CF: select the range `B2:E7` and change the formula to: `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,B:B,B2,$F:$F, "source")=0`. Notice that we **fix** the columns `A` and `F` using `$`, and make the others movable.